# Run camel direct route until data processed in DB

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I have to implement a camel route to run a specific time period. First route to check if there is any record in table. If there is record in the table then run another route to process all records.

```
from("quartz://Timer?cron=0+0/5+20-22+?+*+*")
            .autoStartup(true)
            .routeId("my-route")
            .setBody(constant(sql query))
            .to("jdbc:dataSource?resetAutoCommit=false")
            .choice().when(header("CamelJdbcRowCount").isGreaterThan(0))
                .split(body())
                .setHeader("createdDate", simple("${body['CREATED']}"))
                .inOut("vm:process")
            .end();


    from("vm:process")
            .autoStartup(false)
            .routeId("processrecords")
            .setBody(constant("get all repords query"))
            .to("jdbc:dataSource?readSize=300&useHeadersAsParameters=true&resetAutoCommit=false")
            .split(body())
            .setHeader("Id",simple("${body['ID']}"))
            //do some thing here.
            .setBody(constant("update here onc it is processed."))
            .to("jdbc:dataSource?useHeadersAsParameters=true&resetAutoCommit=false");

}
```

vm:process route should trigger from another route 'my route'. How to run the vm:process route until all the records are processed in the database?

Comment: Instead of `.inOut("vm:process")` use `to("vm:process")`. Both routes have to be started. Probably best is to remove the `autoStartup` directives from your routes.

Comment: @Ralf, Result is same if I use    `to("vm:process")`   instead of    `.inOut("vm:process")`.  "vm:process" processed only 300 records(one batch). Actually my requirement is to process all the records in batches once started the route.

Comment: Then you need to remove the `readSize` limit of 300.

Comment: @Ralf, since the table contains records in millions, it is not good to read all records at same time.

Comment: Why not use the fetchSize on the JDBC level? The JDBC result does not contain the full data set. It is a stream. And in the most aggressive setting it only streams one record of the result set from the DB server to your client. Which requires a lot of network round-trips if your result set is large and is thus very inefficient. So pre-fetching makes sense. But you can reduce the pre-fetch size so your client does not run out of resources.

Comment: If you want to first read and then update millions of records, you will have to wait a long time. Assuming you can process 25 records per second and you are dealing with "just" one million records, then your processing time will be just over 11 hours. Are you sure this is the right approach?